# How to block access to fake links that do not exist?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, .htaccess

I noticed in my Google Analytics account that my website is suddenly hit by a large amount of spam traffic that destroys the visitor statistics. The webserver is running on Ubuntu 18.04 and Apache.

This is even not referral spam where you could track down the source, but seems to be automated bot spam to links that do not exist on my site probably in an attempt to find infected files. The spam bots don't use a full URL and are only visiting certain subdirectory links, for example:

```
/INVOICE-CT/11.php
/INVOICE-CT/1.php
/INVOICE-CT/counter/counter.php
/INVOICE-CT/process.php
/CT/b432.html
/CT/b136.html
/CT/c1428.html
/CT/b246.html
/CT/b510.html
/ct/0295.html
/CT/b118.html
/ct/b385.html
/CT/b738.html
/ct/c1559.html
```

What is the best way to block this kind of traffic in `.htaccess`?

Ideally, this should not interfer with "human-generated" 404 errors.

As Google Analytics does not reveal visitor IPs, how can you identify the bot IPs in Ubuntu to subsequently block them?

Would appreciate your advice.

Comment: Is it these _specific_ URLs you want to block, or can it be generalised? eg. All URLs that simply _start_ `/INVOICE-CT/` or `/CT/`. Or `/CT/` followed by letter, digits and `.html`? Are these similar to real URLs? Could "humans" generate the same 404s?

Comment: Yes, a generalization would work. As these sub-directories do not exist on the website, it would be permissible to block all access to these fake directories: /INVOICE-CT/* or /CT/* and all "content" or fake urls. They have absolutely nothing in common with the content or link structure of the website.

Comment: Have you considered using fail2ban to watch for excessive 404 errors from the same IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following in `.htaccess` to block all URLs that either start `/INVOICE-CT/` or `/CT/`. This uses mod_rewrite to return a system generated (or custom Apache 404 error document if you've defined an `ErrorDocument`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(invoice-)?ct/ - [R=404]
```

Providing your error document does not contain the GA code then GA won't log the request.

> Ideally, this should not interfer with "human-generated" 404 errors.

I assume other 404s are generated by your web application, not Apache? Otherwise, we'd need to rethink the above approach and rewrite to an alternative URL instead.

> As Google Analytics does not reveal visitor IPs, how can you identify the bot IPs in Ubuntu to subsequently block them?

Obviously this method does not identify bot IPs. *Any request* to these wholly invalid URLs will be blocked in the same way. Identifying these malicious bots is not a trivial task and is probably best done with a server module like mod_security or fail2ban.

> What is the best way to block this kind of traffic in `.htaccess`?

The "best way" is probably not to use `.htaccess` (or Apache config) at all, but in your web application itself (in order to prioritise "good" traffic). Only once your application has determined that it's a 404 then check the requested URL. If it is one of these wholly invalid URLs then serve a simple (non-GA) 404 document, otherwise serve your standard 404 error document (that contains for GA code).

> ...large amount of spam traffic that destroys the visitor statistics.

Although presumably this "spam traffic" is already generating 404s and isn't hitting your real URLs?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. The CMS automatically generates the 404 errors for URLs that do not exist. Removing the GA tracking code from the 404 template would just hide the problem, I guess. Ideally that spam traffic should not hit the server at all and waste resources.

Comment: "Removing the GA tracking code from the 404 template would just hide the problem" - The idea would be that you'd have a second "404 template" just for this traffic. But yes, it does "just hide the problem". You can "fail early" using `.htaccess` or the server config (preferable) or fail2ban but you can't stop the requests hitting your application server unless you have an additional proxy server in front that blocks these nasties.